# Replace newlines in ByteString

Tags: haskell, replace, pattern-matching, bytestring

I'd like a function that takes a ByteString and replaces newlines `\n` and `\n\r` with commas, but can't think of a nice way to do it.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Char (ord) 
import Data.Word (Word8)

endlWord8 = fromIntegral $ ord '\n' :: Word8

replace :: BS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
```

I thought of using `BS.map` but can't see how since I can't pattern match on `Word8`'s. Another option would be `BS.split` and then join with Word8 commas, but that sounds slow and inelegant. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `Data.ByteString.Char8` to get rid of the nasty `Word8`, `Char` conversions and back. Shouldn't alter performance according to [Data.ByteString.Char8 first sentence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html). Otherwise `BS.split` doesn't really help, as you also want to repace `\n\r` combinations? I would do a recursive function with `BS.span (/='\n')`. Inelegant, but hopefully not soo slow.

Comment: Thanks, that works! If you write it up as an answer I'll accept

Comment: Gotcha. I can't edit the previous comment, so I hope it won't be too confusing to put it here: @krom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Data.ByteString.Char8` to get rid of the nasty `Word8`, `Char` conversions you otherwise have to do. According to [Data.ByteString.Char8 first sentence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html) performance shouldn't be altered.

Additionally use `B.span` instead of `B.split` as you want to replace also `\n\r` combinations and not only `\n`.

My own (probably clumsy) attempt to do so:

```
module Test where

import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Builder as Build
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB

eatNewline :: ByteString -> (Maybe Char, ByteString)
eatNewline string
  | B.null string = (Nothing, string)
  | B.head string == '\n' && B.null (B.tail string) = (Just ',', B.empty)
  | B.head string == '\n' && B.head (B.tail string) /= '\r' = (Just ',', B.drop 1 string)
  | B.head string == '\n' && B.head (B.tail string) == '\r' = (Just ',', B.drop 2 string)
  | otherwise = (Nothing, string)

replaceNewlines :: ByteString -> ByteString
replaceNewlines = LB.toStrict . Build.toLazyByteString . go mempty
  where
    go :: Build.Builder -> ByteString -> Build.Builder
    go builder string = let (chunk, rest) = B.span (/= '\n') string
                            (c, rest1)    = eatNewline rest
                            maybeComma    = maybe mempty Build.char8 c
                        in if B.null rest1 then
                             builder <> Build.byteString chunk <> maybeComma
                           else
                             go (builder <> Build.byteString chunk <> maybeComma) rest1
```

Hopefully the `mappend` for `Data.ByteString.Builder` isn't linear in the number of times `mappend` was already used for one of its operands, otherwise, there would be a quadratic alogrithm here.